# Decorator Pattern - Access a wrapped ConcreteComponent Value

Tags: c#, design-patterns, decorator

I currently working on an example using the Decorator Pattern.
My current code looks like this:

```
abstract class LibraryItem

    {
        private int _numCopies;

        // Property

        public int NumCopies
        {
            get { return _numCopies; }
            set { _numCopies = value; }
        }

        public abstract void Display();
    }

    /// <summary>

    /// The 'ConcreteComponent' class

    /// </summary>

    class Book : LibraryItem

    {
        private string _author;
        private string _title;

        // Constructor

        public Book(string author, string title, int numCopies)
        {
            this._author = author;
            this._title = title;
            this.NumCopies = numCopies;
        }

        public override void Display()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nBook ------ ");
            Console.WriteLine(" Author: {0}", _author);
            Console.WriteLine(" Title: {0}", _title);
            Console.WriteLine(" # Copies: {0}", NumCopies);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>

    /// The 'ConcreteComponent' class

    /// </summary>

    class Video : LibraryItem

    {
        private string _director;
        private string _title;
        private int _playTime;

        // Constructor

        public Video(string director, string title,
          int numCopies, int playTime)
        {
            this._director = director;
            this._title = title;
            this.NumCopies = numCopies;
            this._playTime = playTime;
        }

        public override void Display()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("3");
            
            Console.WriteLine("\nVideo ----- ");
            Console.WriteLine(" Director: {0}", _director);
            Console.WriteLine(" Title: {0}", _title);
            Console.WriteLine(" # Copies: {0}", NumCopies);
            Console.WriteLine(" Playtime: {0}\n", _playTime);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>

    /// The 'Decorator' abstract class

    /// </summary>

    abstract class Decorator : LibraryItem

    {
        protected LibraryItem libraryItem;

        // Constructor

        public Decorator(LibraryItem libraryItem)
        {
            this.libraryItem = libraryItem;
        }

        public override void Display()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("2");
            libraryItem.Display();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>

    /// The 'ConcreteDecorator' class

    /// </summary>

    class Borrowable : Decorator

    {
        protected List<string> borrowers = new List<string>();

        // Constructor

        public Borrowable(LibraryItem libraryItem)
          : base(libraryItem)
        {
        }

        public void BorrowItem(string name)
        {
            borrowers.Add(name);
            libraryItem.NumCopies--;
        }

        public void ReturnItem(string name)
        {
            borrowers.Remove(name);
            libraryItem.NumCopies++;
        }

        public override void Display()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("1");
            // base.Display();
            this.libraryItem.Display();
            
            foreach (string borrower in borrowers)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" borrower: " + borrower);
            }
        }
    }
```

Now I create a Borrowable-Decorated Video with the following code:

```
Video video = new Video("Spielberg", "Jaws", 23, 92);
Borrowable borrowvideo = new Borrowable(video);
```

What I want to do now, is to access the NumCopies - Property of the borrowvideo-object. The expected value is 23, as I specified that value in the video-constructor, but i get the value 0.

Can someone help me how to get the programm to return 23?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make `NumCopies` virtual and override the behaviour in your decorator base class.

**Side note about decorator pattern:**
In a decorator pattern the `abstract class LibraryItem` should have been an interface. That the decorator is required to implement.

Comment: About that side note, it's not compulsory to have the base as an interface. It could be an Interface and/or Abstract Class depending on your requirement.

Comment: @YashGupta technically you are right, but the idea behind the interface is that the decorator has to change all virtual members. An abstract class leaves an opening for error while an interface not.

Comment: That's correct @verbedr - An abstract class should only be used if there's some commonality (state/behaviour) among all the descendants (that can eventually be moved to some base entity), otherwise an Interface should be the preferred way to go.